# How to use ssh-agent (and graphic passphrase dialog) in Kubuntu 10.10?

Tags: ssh, passwords, kubuntu, ssh-agent

I have recently switched from Ubuntu to kubuntu, both version 10.10. Unfortunately in KDE the ssh passphrase dialog doesn't work out of the box. Everytime my ssh private key is used I need to enter my password. This is neither secure nor comfortable.

I have done comprehensive research on the net but only found out dated documentation. Several things I tried didn't work out. Current status:

- SSH setup working with direct passphrase input
- ssh-agent running in X session
- `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` set to ssh-agent's socket in X session

How to enable ssh-agent for keeping the passphrase in memory for ~15mins and as a bonus always use a graphical dialog for its input?

I use asymmetric SSH key pairs for

- pushing/pulling in Git VCS
- logging remotely into different server systems

Answer (score 1):

Even if `ssh-agent` is running, it's *not* used until you *add* some keys to it - as in `ssh-add`.

As for graphical passphrase inputs, those are *not* part of `ssh-agent` nor `ssh-add`. In GNOME, they're displayed by an entirely different program, GNOME Keyring Daemon (which also acts as a `ssh-agent` replacement). I'm not aware of a KDE analogue.

---

There *is* a way to get graphical input with `ssh-add`, by pointing the `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable to an apropriate "askpass" program, then running `ssh-add < /dev/null`.

I personally use the `pinentry` program from GnuPG (has both KDE and GNOME frontends, but must be used [through a wrapper script](https://github.com/grawity/code/blob/master/tools/askpin)). There seems to be a `ksshaskpass` package available for Ubuntu, too.